# Как интерполировать значения используя Apache Spark?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark

У меня есть Датафрейм в spark

```
+----+---------------+-----------+----------+----------------+
|Year|TotalPopulation|Consumption|Prevalence|MostPopularPrice|
+----+---------------+-----------+----------+----------------+
|1950|     18580.4900|       null|      null|            null|
|1955|     22177.0580|       null|      null|            null|
|1960|     26269.7340|       null|      null|            null|
|1965|     30909.9880|       null|      null|            null|
|1970|     35803.5940|       null|      null|            null|
|1975|     41285.7420|       null|      null|            null|
|1980|     47357.7430|       18.5|      null|            null|
|1981|           null|       18.4|      null|            null|
|1982|           null|  18.200001|      null|            null|
|1983|           null|       18.1|      null|            null|
|1984|           null|         18|      null|            null|
|1985|     54275.8220|         18|      null|            null|
|1986|           null|       17.9|      null|            null|
|1987|           null|  17.799999|      null|            null|
|1988|           null|  17.700001|      null|            null|
|1989|           null|       17.5|      null|            null|
|1990|     61895.1600|  17.299999|      null|            null|
|1991|           null|       17.1|      null|            null|
|1992|           null|       16.9|      null|            null|
|1993|           null|  16.799999|      null|            null|
|1994|           null|       16.6|      null|            null|
|1995|     69784.0880|       16.5|      null|            null|
|1996|           null|       16.4|      null|            null|
|1997|           null|       16.4|      null|            null|
|1998|           null|       16.6|      null|            null|
|1999|           null|         17|      null|            null|
|2000|     77991.7550|       17.4|      34.4|            null|
|2001|           null|       17.9|      null|            null|
|2002|           null|       18.4|      null|            null|
|2003|           null|         19|      null|            null|
|2004|           null|       19.5|      null|            null|
|2005|     86326.2500|         20|      30.6|            null|
|2006|           null|       20.4|      null|            null|
|2007|           null|  20.799999|      null|            null|
|2008|           null|  21.200001|      null|            1.07|
|2009|           null|       21.5|      null|            null|
|2010|     93966.7800|       21.6|      27.6|            1.17|
|2011|           null|       21.5|        27|            null|
|2012|           null|       21.4|      26.5|            1.23|
|2013|           null|       null|      25.9|            null|
|2014|           null|       null|      25.3|            1.86|
|2015|    102113.2120|       null|      24.7|            null|
|2016|    103663.8160|       null|      24.3|            2.85|
|2017|    105172.9250|       null|      null|            null|
|2018|    106651.3940|       null|      null|            3.95|
|2019|    108116.6150|       null|      null|            null|
+----+---------------+-----------+----------+----------------+
```

Часть значений у меня null. 
Как я могу интерполировать null значения в этом Датафрейме? 
Мне нужно сделать интерполяцию примерно с 2005 года

Comment: Ваш `DataFrame` помещается в память на одном узле кластера? Иными словами подойдет ли вам решение на Pandas?

Comment: @MaxU Решение в один кластер помещается. Но, Pandas нельзя использовать) В этом как раз и проблема)

Comment: а зачем тогда тег `pandas` ?